# Set environment variable in ubuntu for ionic

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, operating-system

Hi everybody i have tried very hard to solve this but not able to get success. **Please help me**

**I am trying to build ionic android application**. Look at screen shot

*i have ionic, cordova,node and working android command*

[image]

My problem is, **I am not able to save $ANDROID_HOME environment variable in ubuntu 15.10**.

I follow these steps which are shown below in the screen

[image]

**I am not able to understand what is happening over here**

Comment: Please check screen shots i have sdk installed and able to use android command

Comment: I have also check these variable 
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/android-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already set $ANDROID_HOME in ~/.profile and also tried to export from terminal but i was getting the same error again and again.

**Problem was** i was using this command with **sudo**

```
sudo ionic build android
```

when i used this command without sudo it worked fine

```
ionic build android
```

***But to use this command without sudo, change the permission of bower-github.json file***

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/username/.config/configstore/bower-github.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this In the console just type these (remember to change to your current location)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/dquintana/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/dquintana/Android/Sdk/tools
```

If want it to make it permanent just add those lines in the ~/.bashrc file

Comment: I have check these variable
 $ export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/ 
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk/ 
But it is not working

Comment: also my $PATH is 
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/node/bin:/opt/gradle/bin:/tools:/platform-tools:/bin

Comment: `export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/      export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH`     Make sure the android sdk is installed in the folder _/opt/android-sdk/_ and inside the folder, there are two folders called platforms and platform tools